# Translating to query algebra

Tags: database, algebra

Can anyone translate this SQL query into query algebra?

```sql
SELECT P.PNAME, SUM(SH.QTY) 
FROM PARTS P, SHIPMENTS SH
WHERE P.PNUM = SH.PNUM
GROUP BY P.PNAME
HAVING SUM(SH.QTY) > 300
```

I just don't know how to incorporate *Group By* and *Having* SUM(SH.QTY) to my query algebra.

Comment: are you understand this query what is output and why ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 tables in DB.

1. PARTS
2. SHIPMENTS

This query give the output from these two tables.

[Group By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement is use for an aggregate.

The Example of this is given [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm)

Group by is like that you are given a set of different names including repeating names. so you have to just select unique names like intersection works.

[Sum](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) function will sum the QTY column of shipments table.

The Example is given [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp)

[Here is Group By and sum description in Algebra](http://0agr.ru/wiki/index.php/Translating_SQL_to_Relational_Algebra#Joins)

The output is like this

```html
<table border="1" width=300>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hamza</td>
    <td>500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hafeez</td>
    <td>400</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know the output, I'm interested in the query algebra expression